# How make background circlular fade

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, sdk, uiwebview

I'm not sure what it's called, I have UIView with UIWebView in it, and I want make it exactly as the screen shot below while UIWebView is loading.

Can anybody help me with that?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you can use https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD  with

```
hud.dimBackground = YES;
```